# jquery - get value of $(this) checked radio option in a click event callback

Tags: jquery

Checking for the value of a radio button series, I have this code:

```
$('input:radio[name="question13"]').click(
    function() {
        if ($('input:radio[name="question13"]:checked').val() == 'Yes') {
            $('input[name="file_upload"]').prop('required', true)
        } else if ($('input:radio[name="question13"]:checked').val() == 'No') {
            $('input[name="file_upload"]').removeProp('required')
        }
    }
).triggerHandler('click');
```

This works, but can you do it with `$(this)` instead of `$('input:radio[name="question13"]:checked')` in the callback?

Comment: I mean... Yes? exactly as you have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have just Yes/No, then you can do:

```
var isYes = $(this).val() == "Yes";
```

as you can only click on a radio to set it, or, put another way, any click on a radio will make that radio `:checked`.

---

If there's more options and you want to know which option, then as it's a radio and you want to get the related `:checked` element (which may be a different element), then you need to get the `name` of the clicked radio:

```
$(this).attr("name")
```

or just

```
this.name
```

then find the related `:checked` input:

```
$(`input:radio[name="${this.name}"]:checked`)
```

Here's an example snippet using some extrapolated HTML and including one handler for two "questions":

```js
$('input:radio').click(function() {
  var yesNo = $(`input:radio[name="${this.name}"]:checked`).val();
  
  // do something with Yes/No
  $(this).nextAll("div").first().text(yesNo === "Yes" ? "*" : "");
});
```

```css
input + div { display: inline-block; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='radio' name='question13' value='Yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' name='question13' value='No'>No
<div></div>

<hr/>

<input type='radio' name='question14' value='Yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' name='question14' value='No'>No
<div></div>
```

---

In the case that you only have Yes/No values, you can extrapolate that if the element you clicked is not checked, then the other one is.

Making a much simpler check:

```
var isYes = $(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() == "Yes";
```

but given that you can't "uncheck" a `radio`, if you're clicking on it, then `:checked` must be the one you're clicking on, giving just:

```
var isYes = $(this).val() == "Yes";
```

```js
$('input:radio').click(function() {
  var isYes = $(this).val() == "Yes";
  
  // do something with Yes/No
  $(this).nextAll("div").first().text(isYes ? "*" : "");
});
```

```css
input + div { display: inline-block; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='radio' name='question13' value='Yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' name='question13' value='No'>No
<div></div>

<hr/>

<input type='radio' name='question14' value='Yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' name='question14' value='No'>No
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great.  I would point out, though, that I can't extrapolate the value based on which one is clicked because this should also work with .triggerHandler('click') on reload.

Comment: Just added that part as it looked like Yes/No - you can use the `$(``input:radio[name="${this.name}"]:checked``)` part.

Comment: Both work well. I can just use ```$(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() == "Yes"  else if $(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() == "No" ```.  Thanks so much for the detailed answer.